# transform:scale() on image with padding

Tags: html, css, transform, scale

I want to zoom in on the image on hover but I don't want to it to expand.
works fine if you remove the padding on the image but i need it for other reasons.
Is there anyway to make the transition:scale() not to go over the padding area?
How it looks now: https://jsfiddle.net/8u84shbe/

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://s12.postimg.org/db0vuer0t/Koala.jpg">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://s12.postimg.org/db0vuer0t/Koala.jpg">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://s12.postimg.org/db0vuer0t/Koala.jpg">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://s12.postimg.org/db0vuer0t/Koala.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:10px;
}
.item img:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25);
    /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25);
    /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25);
    /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1.25);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Will giving border instead of padding work for you**?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8u84shbe/1/

CSS:

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:10px solid #FFF;
}
.item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.item img:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25);
    /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25);
    /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25);
    /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1.25);
```

Comment: It would be better to set transparent borders instead of white. So images can be positioned on colored background.

Comment: @isqua That depends on  the OP what color he wants to use there